# How to calculate duration for a BerkeleyDB dump/load operation for a given BDB file?

Tags: berkeley-db

I'm using a 3rd party application that uses BerkeleyDB for its local datastore (called BMC Discovery). Over time, its BDB files fragment and become ridiculously large, and BMC Software scripted a compact utility that basically uses db_dump piped into db_load with a new file name, and then replaces the original file with the rebuilt file.

The time it can take for large files is insanely long, and can take hours, while some others for the same size take half that time. It seems to really depend on the level of fragmentation in the file and/or type of data in it (I assume?).

The utility provided uses a crude method to guestimate the duration based on the total size of the datastore (which is composed of multiple BDB files). Ex. if larger than 1G say "will take a few hours" and if larger than 100G say "will take many hours". This doesn't help at all.

I'm wondering if there would be a better, more accurate way, using the commands provided with BerkeleyDB.6.0 (on Red Hat), to estimate the duration of a db_dump/db_load operation for a specific BDB file ?

Note: Even though this question mentions a specific 3rd party application, it's just to put you in context. The question is generic to BerkelyDB.

Answer (score 0):

db_dump/db_load are the usual (portable) way to defragment.

Newer BDB (like last 4-5 years, certainly db-6.x) has a db_hotbackup(8) command that might be faster by avoiding hex conversions.

(solutions below would require custom coding)

There is also a DB->compact(3) call that "optionally returns unused Btree, Hash or Recno database pages to the underlying filesystem.". This will likely lead to a sparse file which will appear ridiculously large (with "ls -l") but actually only uses the blocks necessary to store the data.

Finally, there is db_upgrade(8) / db_verify(8), both of which might be customized with DB->set_feedback(3) to do a callback (i.e. a progress bar) for long operations.

Before anything, I would check configuration using db_tuner(8) and db_stat(8), and think a bit about tuning parameters in DB_CONFIG.